# How to change ember-data instances across adapters

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js, local-storage, ember-data

I'm planning on making an offline friendly application which can then synchronize the state of the store with my backend API. What's a good pattern for using the localstorage adapter then having the application, through user input or state of the data, initialize a synchronization? Would regular AJAX calls be best? Or can I have two adapters for a ember-data in memory table then switch what adapter is used?

Here's the localstorage adapter I'm considering: https://github.com/kurko/ember-localstorage-adapter

Answer (score 3):

check orbit.js it work nice with ember and ember-data.

1. https://github.com/orbitjs/orbit.js
2. https://github.com/orbitjs/ember-orbit
3. nice presentation from wicked ember conf https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omc4pnXv1Ds

Comment: The guide for ember-orbit specifically mentions removing ember-data from the project so I'm not sure it works nice. This is, however, a fascinating option.

Comment: Yes, Orbit.js is a replacement for ember-data not a layer behind it.